# What is the absolute value of the following?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

So the expression is as follows

$$
\frac{e^{-jk \left(r+d\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}}{r}
+ \frac{e^{j\varphi}e^{-jk \left(r-d\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}}{r}
$$

I factored out the $\frac{e^{-jkr}}{r}$ and took the absolute value of this which is $\frac{1}{r}$ this leaves the absolute value of $e^{-jkd\cos\theta/2} + e^{j\phi}e^{jkd\cos\theta/2}$.

However, I can't solve the remaining term and hoped for help.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.

Comment: @Brian I apologise for this and thanks for the edit

Comment: Please clarify whether $j,k,d,\theta,r,\phi$ are all complex or strictly real.

Comment: @Jam j is the only complex value and it is is equivalent to i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note

$$|e^{-jkd\cos\theta/2} + e^{j\phi}e^{jkd\cos\theta/2}|^2$$
$$=(e^{-jkd\cos\theta/2} + e^{j\phi}e^{jkd\cos\theta/2})
(e^{jkd\cos\theta/2} + e^{-j\phi}e^{-jkd\cos\theta/2})$$
$$=1+ e^{j\phi}e^{2jkd\cos\theta/2} + e^{-j\phi}e^{-2jkd\cos\theta/2} +1$$
$$=2+ 2\cos(\phi+2kd\cos\theta/2)  $$

Thus, the absolute value is

$$\frac{\sqrt2}r\sqrt{1+\cos(\phi+2kd\cos\theta/2) }$$

Comment: Strictly speaking, that would be for $r>0$, otherwise it would be $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{|r|}\cdot\sqrt{\ldots}$.

Answer (score 1):

For notational simplicity, let $a=r+d\cos\frac{\theta}{2},\ b=r-d\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$. Recall that the magnitude of a complex number, $|z|=\sqrt{z\cdot z^*}$, is the square root of the product of the number with its conjugate and that for all complex numbers, $(z+w)^*=z^*+w^*$ and $\left(\frac{z}{w}\right)^*=\frac{z^*}{w^*}$, and that the conjugate of a number in polar form is $re^{i\theta}\mapsto re^{-i\theta} $. Then, the square of the magnitude is
$$|z|^2=\left(\frac{e^{-jka}}{r}+\frac{e^{j\varphi}e^{-jkb}}{r}\right)\left(\frac{e^{-jka}}{r}+\frac{e^{j\varphi}e^{-jkb}}{r}\right)^{*}
\\
=\frac{\left(e^{-jka}+e^{j\left(\varphi-kb\right)}\right)}{r}\frac{\left(\left(e^{-jka}\right)^{*}+\left(e^{j\left(\varphi-kb\right)}\right)^{*}\right)}{r^{*}}
\\
=\frac{\left(e^{-jka}+e^{j\left(\varphi-kb\right)}\right)\left(e^{jka}+e^{-j\left(\varphi-kb\right)}\right)}{r^{2}}
$$

You should be able to take it from here.